# Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: Connection refused php

Tags: php, wordpress

today after updating a piece of content on my WP website I've got this error showing up (instead of some icons images):

Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/icon-linkedin.svg): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /home/user/mywebsite/htdocs/wp-content/themes/theabnet/front-page.php on line 28

This is the screenshot of the code generating the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7A6.png

The weird thing is that this never happened before and the edit I made was not involving icons or things directly connected with that navigation area.

Any help? (No strong coding skills unfortunately).

Comment: Does the error message actually say: "www.mywebsite.com"? Or did you change that for this question? The wanted file does not exist there.

Comment: Note that you're using the `http` protocol, and not a normal file path. Your PHP, and your web server, have to allow this protocol. You might need to use `https` or a normal file path.

Answer (score 0):

> Any help? (No strong coding skills unfortunately).

Revert the changes and see if your website recovers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving folder permission in your live server sometimes permission. If it is your own, try to re-register the domain (or) change the SVG icon link.

Answer (score -1):

I think the domain name (mywebsite.com) of your requested SVG link is wrong. If it is your own, try to re-register domain (or) change SVG icon link.

Comment: I've changed the domain name in the code I pasted for privacy reasons. The URL in the original code is correct, so that's not the issue – but thanks.

Comment: Ok I see, since you used get_sub_field('icon'), icon is save as ACF field. Another possible one is save image as (image array or image id). Is it set as Image URL? you can check in the setting. If not, it may only relate to file_get_contents. Hope it help.